# Euler and probability - a $\zeta$-distributed random variable

Tags: probability, arithmetic

Let's consider a random variable $X$ on  $\mathbb{N}^*$ such as $\mathbb{P}[X=n]=n^{-s}\zeta(s)$.

Thanks to that random variable we can prove that 
$\zeta(s)= \underset{i=1}{\overset{\infty}{\prod}}\frac{1}{1-p_i^{-s}}$, where $p_i$ is the $i^\text{th}$ prime number, by calculating the probability of the event $\mathbb{P}[k \mid X]$.
Then there a question I couldn't solve.

Let's take a random variable $Y$ defined on $\mathbb{N}^*$, which has the same distribution of $X$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Calculate the distribution of $Z = \gcd(X,Y)$ where $\gcd$ represents the greatest common divisor.

I would be grateful for any suggestions or ideas.

Comment: What do you mean the expression for $\zeta(s)$ is proved using $X$?  First $\zeta(s)$ is defined as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-s}$, and then this expression is derived through entirely different means.

Comment: How come there's an $s$ on the right hand side of the expression for $P[X=n]$? The probability shouldn't vary with $s$? If $s$ is fixed, what is it?

Comment: @HowDoIMath: $s$ is just a parameter. The probability depends on $n$.

Comment: @dsaxton: the OP was probably meaning that, if we define $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s}$, we can prove the Euler formula for the zeta function through a probabilistic argument. That is pretty nice, indeed.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio ok, so I can think of the variable $X$ as being indexed by $s$, as in $X_s$? If I recall correctly, it is only a measure for Re(s)>1 (maybe we only want real $s$)

Comment: @HowDoIMath: just assume that $s$ is a real number greater than one, there is no need here of analytic continuations, complex numbers or complex measures.

Answer (score 4):

Let we compute the probability that $Z=1$, for first. Given two random integers $X,Y$, they are coprime if for every prime $p$ such a prime divides at most one of them. So, what is the probability that $X$ is even? It is:

$$ \mathbb{P}[X\text{ is even}]=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2n)^s} = \frac{1}{2^s}$$
In the same way we have that the probability that $p$ divides $X$ is exactly $\frac{1}{p^s}$. Now it is important to check that given two different primes $p,q$, the events $X\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ and $X\equiv 0\pmod{q}$ are independent. The unique factorization theorem grants that.

So we have:
$$ \mathbb{P}[Z=1] = \prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{2s}}\right) = \frac{1}{\zeta(2s)}.$$
Now I bet you can prove from this argument that:
$$ \mathbb{P}[Z=m] = \frac{1}{\zeta(2s)}\cdot\frac{1}{m^{2s}}.$$

Comment: hello, Jack D'Aurizio, thanks for the interest for this question, I completely agree with you with the calculus of $P[Z=1]$, but the calculus of $P[Z=m]$ seems wrong because $\underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}\mathbb{P}(Z=k)\neq 1$

Comment: @ashu24: you are right, now fixed. The point is that: in order to choose $X$ and $Y$ such that $\gcd(X,Y)=m$, we choose two coprime integers and multiply them both by $m$.

Comment: Thank you very much Jack, I also got that $\mathbb{P}(Z=m)=\frac{1}{\zeta(2s)}\frac{1}{m^{2s}}$. I will write a complete answer, soon including the probability demonstration of the Euler's formula if some people are curious about that.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Hi can you prove the last argument ?Because you would lose the bet in my case,unfortunately.Thank you!